# how to add static(html,js) files for grpc

Tags: go, grpc, handler, proto

I have a grpc client and server. I have a protofile. I am using a grpc gateway and I want to use html for the client. There is a path `localhost:8081/test`, I would like it to be an html file when I go through this path. **How can I tell the handler to give the html file in the response?
what should the handler look like?**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "/go_proto";
package api;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service authorization{
  rpc Test(testRequest) returns (testResponse){
    option(google.api.http) = {
      get: "/test"
    };
  }
   
}

message testRequest{
}

message testResponse{
  int32 arg1 = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you cannot (directly).

[gRPC Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) is one way (Envoy's [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) is another) to expose gRPC services as (JSON) REST APIs.

In your example, the above solutions will enable you to make HTTP `GET` calls against `/test` returning a JSON representation of `testResponse` (`{"arg1":...}`).

If you want to serve HTML, see [Adding custom routes to the mux](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/docs/operations/inject_router/) this would allow you to write a handler that serves HTML.

> **NOTE** This HTML handler could include JavaScript that uses e.g. [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to `GET` the `/test`endpoint.

Have a look at [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) too. This requires Node.JS but it provides a gRPC client for JavaScript as an alternative to the REST client described above.

If you want to expose gRPC services with REST APIs, then use [gRPC Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) or Envoy's [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter). This gives you the ability to have clients that use gRPC **and** REST.

If you want to have only gRPC clients, [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) gives Node.JS developers access to your gRPC services too.